# Access Denied 2003 server shared printer on Vista

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-vista, network-share, printing, shared-printers

Here's the facts.

I have a Domain Controller running Windows 2003 Server R2 (Standard edition) with up to now only XP Client in a High School environment. I have an accounting system to manage how much student can print on my server so the printer installed on student account must be the shared and not a standard TCP/IP port...

Now, I'm testing migration to Windows Vista SP2 (Ultimate for my tests maybe Business later). Everything works fine except Shared Printers on my 2003 DC.

On my account (full admin rights) everything works, but on a student account (so very restricted access) I can't use those printer, I always get "Access Denied" to them. On XP client, it's still working fine.

What I've done right now :

- Added the "Authentificated  users" and "students" groups to the security printer to allow them to print to it, result, still getting Access Denied...
- Tried to add local port on the serveur to reflect the share name (solution found by comme googling), not working either...

So, I'm searching for a solution to allow my students to print on their account on Vista client as the same as on XP client.

Is there a solution or I'm I screwed with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved!

Instead of adding a network printer, I added a local printer. You must create a new local port that has the same name of you network share. Exemple, if you printer is shared under \mysvr\print1 you should create a localport named \mysvr\print1 and then it'll work like magic!

Thanks anyway for those who had take the time to read my post.